# How to download an array from firestore. Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
private void downloadArray(){
    final DocumentReference docRef = database.collection("Users").document(uid);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                ArrayList<String> ArrayFromFirestore= (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("categories");
                CopyArray.addAll(ArrayFromFirestore);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

CopyArray is private class variable. I try to copy one array into another, and despite the fact my ArrayFromFirestore have got elements inside, CopyArray always has 0
Can I modify variables from outside of this function?

Comment: What exactly are you doing to observe that CopyArray is empty?  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and please also show us the content of your `addAll()` method.

Comment: Have you give it a try using the [arraycopy()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) method to copy the values from one array to another?